# Separating answers to gauge community response

Tags: discussion

In this [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/299319/3306), I replied with documentation from both sides of the debate:

- *That* and *which* are equivalent.
- *That* and *which* differ.

Would it be more helpful to the community to separate these into two responses? By separating these into the Language Log and Strunk & White answers, the more favored response would float to the top.

Or would a single, comprehensive answer serve the community better?

Comment: It's my personal opinion, but I think the question should be closed as duplicate. I posted a related question in the first comment planning to close-vote it later and waited for others to vote first. Your answer seems similar to those posted in the duplicate question. Do you think it is not a duplicate?

Comment: I would agree that it's a duplicate question. Unlike the existing answers, my answer embraces both sides with references to the critiqued S&W.

Comment: Should the question be closed, what happens to the bounty? Does it get returned to the OP?

Comment: @rajah9 Your question does not address both sides at all, I'm afraid. Mentioning one 'side' and then detailing and 'explaining' another is not the equivalent of giving two sides to a story. Not that there really are two stories here.